# Domain Access and mother website arguments

Tags: domain-access

I am thinking of creating a series of websites based on one mother website using the Domain Access module, like this:

www.domain1.com linking to www.motherwebsite.com/argument1

www.domain2.com linking to www.motherwebsite.com/argument2

www.domain3.com linking to www.motherwebsite.com/argument3

etc. Each child domain will show the content associated with this domain (but created on the mother website) depending on argumentN.

So, my question is how can I capture the argumentN data to deliver the corresponding content (in Views, Blocks, Panels etc)? I guess I won't be able to use the URL for that as the argument data will not be part of the child domain's URL...

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed the [Domain Access](https://drupal.org/project/domain) module, you will have the [Domain Access Views](https://drupal.org/project/domain_views) module available. First thing you want to do is enable that module if you haven't already.

Once you've done that, you can use the current domain as a filter:

1. Under Filter Criteria, add "Domain Access: Domain ID"
2. "Operator" is one of "Current Domain"

Now the view will only return nodes for the domain that the block/page is loaded from.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Scott! Just another question - how do I associate nodes with this domain if they are created on the mother website? They will have the argumentN as one of their CCK fields, but no other link to the needed domain...

Comment: @Mark, on each node there is a "Domain access options" tab. By default, "Send to all affiliates" is checked, which will add the node to all domains. If you uncheck that box and then check the box(es) next to the domain you want the node to show on, you'll be in business.